# Python 3.4: href with XPATH

Tags: python, xpath

Using `lxml` and `requests` I am passing a `XPATH` to retrieve `href` attributes of `a` tags.  Every time I use the simple code below I get an `AttributeError` as exemplified below.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import csv




url = 'https://biz.yahoo.com/p/sum_conameu.html'

resp = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(resp.text)

update_tick = [td.text_content()
               for td in tree.xpath('''//tr[starts-with(normalize-space(.), "Industry")]
                                        /following-sibling::tr[position()>0]
                                        /td/a/@href''')]

print(update_tick)


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text_content'
```

Comment: update_tick is already text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing XPath attribute selector (`.../@href`) to `xpath()` method make it return string values of the matched attributes. No need to call `text_content()` in this case :

```
update_tick = [td
               for td in tree.xpath('''//tr[starts-with(normalize-space(.), "Industry")]
                                        /following-sibling::tr[position()>0]
                                        /td/a/@href''')]
```